# Looking for advice on security and privacy for setting up a website

Tags: database, security, web, server, configuration

Planning on starting my own website where users can interact with one another but would want some advice regarding the security/privacy. Looking for someone with experience to be able to tell me from A to Z (from nothing to finished product) and how to maintain the website.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], this isn't an appropriate SO question.

Comment: Welcome to SO, if you want to learn more about website security then OWASP (https://owasp.org/) is great place to start. Then, as per the previous comment, please do come back with some more specific and targeted questions for SO.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.